# Python/Pandas: dataframe merge and fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, ffill

I try to merge two Pandas dataframes based on date and then ffill `NaN` values until specific date. I have the following data example:

df_1:

| date | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 01/12 | 10 |
| 02/12 | 20 |
| 03/12 | 30 |
| 04/12 | 40 |
| 05/12 | 60 |
| 06/12 | 70 |
| 07/12 | 80 |

df_2:

| date | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 01/12 | 100 |
| 03/12 | 300 |
| 05/12 | 500 |

I use the following line:
`df = pd.merge((df_1,df_2, how='left', on=['date']`

I get this:

| date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/12 | 10 | 100 |
| 02/12 | 20 | NaN |
| 03/12 | 30 | 300 |
| 04/12 | 40 | Nan |
| 05/12 | 50 | 500 |
| 06/12 | 60 | NaN |
| 07/12 | 70 | NaN |

What I want to achieve then is to forwardfill the `NaN` values in `df['value2']` until `05/12` and not until `07/12`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'forwardfill'? A dataframe needs an entry of every row column combination and if there are no values, I think you're stuck with NaN. If you want to set specific values to value2 for dates after 6/12, you could do that, but you have to choose the values if you're not happy with NaN.

Comment: For 'value2' it should look like this: 100,100,300,300,500,500,NaN,NaN. Basically using the fillna(method='ffill') but until 05/12. However with fillna() it will fill the NaN values until the end of the dataframe(07/12)

Comment: @kobo do approve the solution if it helped you :D

Answer (score 2):

First, convert date to `datetime` format to use conditional operand. It will return YYYY-MM-DD by default.

Next, create a mask for your condition `ffill` to `05/12`. and use `loc` for `fillna`.

Lastly, convert back `date` from `datetime` back to `string`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%d/%m")
mask = (df["date"].lt(pd.to_datetime('05/12', format="%d/%m")))
df.loc[mask, "val2"] = df.loc[mask, "val2"].fillna(method="ffill")
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m')
```